# neo4j HA structure in embedded mode

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to have this structure in my application using neo4j database.

[image]

Here i am deploying my application on three different servers and each is having its own embedded neo4j database.

I want all databases are in sync automatically.

Is it fine for my big size data application?

I am using Spring data neo4j,how to configure this structure in SDN.

Do i need Enterprise edition of neo4j for this.

Any other framework/technology which can be used?

I have almost done the structure like this

My web application is deployed on

1. localhost:8088        xml-> ha.server_id = 1 and dbptah = E:/data1
2. localhost:8089        xml-> ha.server_id = 2 and dbptah = E:/data2
3. localhost:8090        xml-> ha.server_id = 3 and dbptah = E:/data3

Neo4j server is running on :

1. localhost:7474        properties-> ha.server_id = 1 and dbptah = E:/data1
2. localhost:7475        properties-> ha.server_id = 2 and dbptah = E:/data2
3. localhost:7476        properties-> ha.server_id = 3 and dbptah = E:/data3

now when i run my web application it gives me error :

```
Caused by StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file:
```

It seems that it can not get access to directory which is being used by neo4j server then how i confiigure xml in my web app??

Comment: Are you running standalone servers too? If you are, you should stop them, Neo4J embedded is a fully functional server embedded in your java application.

Comment: @JohnMark13 but i want clustering,then for clustering i think i have to run standalone servers.

Comment: No you do not. That was what my first comment on my answer below said too. I am running an HA cluster using SDN and no standalone instances. You can mix both. Whatever you are doing though, you should not have two instances referencing the same db directory.

Comment: So shut down the standalone servers and you can just use your web application instances if it uses the config I provided.

Comment: @JohnMark13 i stopped,now let's say there is no neo4j server running on my machine,and i have three instances of my web application and each is having different server_id and DBPATH.is it ok?nut now my web applications are not getting up,it seems they are waiting for initial hosts or something,no error just waiting..

Comment: (This is probably a new question now) You might need to set additional properties as they are all on the same machine, add values into the `<util:map />` config to match what is required in the example here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html#ha-local-cluster

Comment: @JohnMark13 could you plz tell me about  <entry key="ha.initial_hosts" value="thisserver.com:5001,yoursecondserver.com:5001,yourthirdserver.com:5001"/> here what are thisserver,yoursecondserver etc. and do we need to start them manuallly??

Comment: I created a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63399/neo4j-ha-structure-in-embedded-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question, yes running Neo4j-enterprise (HA) with SDN is great for a project with large aounts of data sitting behind a load balancer. There is one issue that I am aware of and that is that SDN has not been developed to understand HA. This has caused one issue for me in that certain operations can only be performed (and I mean *only*) on the master node, so you have to code arround that.

SDN with HA is easy to configure once you've found out how! This is the code I use and was originally borrowed from [Stefan Armbruster](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/08/configuring-a-neo4j-graphdatabaseservice-via-spring/).

```
<util:map id="config">
   <entry key="ha.server_id" value="1"/>
   <entry key="ha.initial_hosts" value="thisserver.com:5001,yoursecondserver.com:5001,yourthirdserver.com:5001"/>
</util:map>

<bean id="graphDbFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory"/>

<bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory" factory-method="newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder">
     <constructor-arg value="/tmp/neo4j"/>
</bean>

<bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder" factory-method="setConfig">
    <constructor-arg ref="config"/>
</bean>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" />
```

In the map at the top you can put any of the settings that you might find in the documentation [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html) and [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-configuration.html). Once your cluster is running you can drop new nodes in, the requirement is that the ha.server_id value is unique, but initial_hosts does not need to be fully populated. Your life will be more simple if you set values for the ha.server and ha.cluster_server properties.

For performance you will want to try to minimise writes on your Slave nodes, there is some excellent documentation on how to achieve this on teh [Neo Site](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-haproxy.html), essentially configuring your load balancer to make routing decisions based on the responses from the special HA endpoints.

```
/db/manage/server/ha/master
/db/manage/server/ha/slave
/db/manage/server/ha/available
```

Unfortunately I could not use that, so for non critical writes I post them off to a message queue which is only processed on the Master node.

HA will automatically keep your data in sync and will enable live backups too, elections will be performened when the Master dies to promte another cluster member. Since Neo moved away from ZooKepper it is trivial to setup.

Now, the tough part. Licensing. HA is enterprise and as far as I understand the application of the APGL, you need to either buy a license or open source your code. There is another license model on the site `personal` which will allow you and a small team (+2 people) make software which can take up to $100000 but you'll be left with just SO for support...

Any other frameworks, probably, but not that I am familiar with - [Graphene](http://www.graphenedb.com/) would probably be a good place to start investigating though if you want to offload the scaling responsibility.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have one question,i think we don't need any neo4j server in embedded mode then while setting HA,what does initial hosts mean?Do i need to run as many neo4j servers separately?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. If you are running embedded you do not *need* any standalone servers, but by all means you can cluster embedded + standalone. In both cases you need to set initial hosts which defines the shape of the initial cluster.

Comment: I want to use embedded mode and want to cluster my database,then do i need to have multiple neo4j servers running on different machines/ports?If yes then where the data will be?As specified in your example,will data be in tmp/neo4j and all three clusters?
and last last thing,as in my diagram if i want to deploy my application on multiple servers then neo4j configuration will be same or different for each application?

Comment: also when i used your configuration,i am getting neo4j template null

Comment: If you want a cluster then yes you need Neo4J running on multiple machines and/or ports. The data will be wherever you set it to be on each and every machine (/tmp/neo4j above, but you can set it to anything), *all* data will be replicated. Config will be largely the same across all instances, but as a minimum you must have a different value for ha.server_id on each.

Comment: Thanks,i am facing one issue,please check my updated question.

Comment: i am using SDN in grails application and i also want to use spring security rest plugin but didn't get any solution for this,do you have any idea about how to integrate grails spring security rest plugin with SDN?